# The orthogonal projection over the subspace $V=\{f:f =0\text{ on }[0,1/2]\}$

Tags: functional-analysis

The orthogonal projection of an element $x_0 \in H$ over a convex set $C$ is the element $y_0 \in C$ such that $\|x_0-y_0\|=\min_{y \in C}\|x_0-y\|$. Find the orthogonal projection of $\gamma (x)=2e^{2\pi ix}$ over the subspace $V=\{f:f =0\text{ on }[0,1/2]\}$.

The orthogonal projection of $2e^{2\pi ix}$ onto the subspace $M=\{\lambda g: \lambda \in C\}$ is the unique $\lambda g$ such that

$$(2e^{2\pi ix}-\lambda g) \perp M$$

Equivalently we must find $\lambda$ such that

$$\int_0^1 (2e^{2\pi ix}-\lambda g)g \,dx=0$$

How do I continue with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stated the space $H$. I'll assume $H=L^{2}[0,1]$. The orthogonal projection $P_{V}\gamma$ of $\gamma$ onto $V$ is the unique $f \in V$--if it exists--such that
$$
          (\gamma-f,g)=0,\;\;\; g \in V.
$$
Every $g \in V$ has the property that $g\chi_{(1/2,1]}=g$ because such $g$ vanishes on $[0,1/2]$. You might guess that
$$
           f= P_{V}\gamma = \chi_{(1,2,1]}\gamma,
$$
but it can be directly verified because
$$
          (\gamma-\chi_{(1,2,1]}\gamma,g)=(\gamma\chi_{[0,1/2]},g\chi_{(1/2,1]})=0,\;\;\; g \in V.
$$
So $P_{V}(2e^{2\pi ix})=2\chi_{(1/2,1]}(x)e^{2\pi ix}$. Because the orthogonal projection exists for each $\gamma \in L^{2}[0,1]$, it follows that $V$ is a closed subspace of $X$, too. Automatically $P=P^{2}=P^{\star}$ on $L^{2}[0,1]$.